# Code coverage warning using schema aware XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm interested if there are any code coverage warnings - basically warning saying lines or sections of code cannot be type checked, or any basic techniques for ensuring that such sections don't exist.

To illustrate I have an XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:complexType name="SQUARETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="kind"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FILLEDSQUARETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="kind"/>

    <xs:attribute name="colour" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRIANGLETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SQUARE">
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TRIANGLE">
    <xs:alternative type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="rootShape">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
        <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and an xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxsl"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:import-schema schema-location="MessingAbout.xsd"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="schema-element(SQUARE)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="@colour"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, I think, has 100% coverage (though the initial match on "/" isnt checked).

If I were to amend the xslt to say this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxsl"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:import-schema schema-location="MessingAbout.xsd"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SQUARE"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="@colour"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then there line

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SQUARE"/>
```

isnt checked, I can replace "SQUARE" with "SQUARE1" and this will not be checked (understandably).

Is it possible to turn on some setting that warns me of this? So I can enforce that my XSLTs are always type checked? (even if that excludes certain "valid", but non type checkable programs (this is a common trade off)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all type-checked, but the thoroughness of the static type checking depends on how much type information is available. So it's not a black-and-white 0% or 100%. Basically, at compile time the processor does all the type checking it can, and defers the rest till run time. There are some checks Saxon doesn't attempt even if its theoretically possible, for example anything involving axes other than child, attribute, and descendant.

Comment: ok...hmmmm...is there a style of programming that will always be type checked? simple for-each, no fancy axes?

Comment: P.S. I suspect its a matter of opinion, but does XQuery tend to have fewer compile time type holes in it?

Comment: Yes, XQuery is more statically decidable than XSLT, because it doesn't have the dynamic despatch mechanism of template rules. In XQuery 1.0 there was also a "strict static typing" option in which anything that might fail at run-time becomes a static error; but that didn't prove very usable (it's mainly found today, I think, in Microsoft's SQL Server implementation). And it was achieved partly by restricting the axes you can use for navigation, which is horrible.

Comment: so saxon doesnt do the strict static typing option?

Comment: tbh, this is exactly what I could do with, correctness in my context is the principle issue, even at the expense of restricting certain behaviours.